# How to make Telerik's RadHtmlChart legend to be displayed in two columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am working on an asp.net webforms project. I am using Telerik's RadHtmlChart control. I would like to display the legend in two columns. Currently it is displayed as a single column. I tried to make the height of the small so it will into two or more columns. But it didn't work.

RadHtmlChart2.Legend.Appearance.Height.Equals(20);

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of RadHtmlChart's Legend is to show information which is connected with the displayed data, there is no property which allows populating custom legend items.

The NameField property is specific for PieSeries, DonutSeries and BubbleSeries, but you can achieve the same appearance in BarSeries and ColumnSeries by setting their Name property:

```
<telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="yValue" Name="column series"></telerik:ColumnSeries>
```

Specifying a Name property for a series creates an "item" in the legend. Note that this property is used for setting series' names explicitly and the NameField property is its equivalent in a databind scenario.

I also attach a sample page where I have databound a ColumnSeries and set its Name property, so you can check my suggestions.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Legend-Bar-Column.aspx.cs" Inherits="TICKETS_Chart_2013_Q3_Legend_Bar_Column_Legend_Bar_Column" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />

        <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="Chart" Skin="Black">
            <PlotArea>
                <Series>
                    <telerik:ColumnSeries DataFieldY="yValue" Name="column series"></telerik:ColumnSeries>
                </Series>
            </PlotArea>
        </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TICKETS_Chart_2013_Q3_Legend_Bar_Column_Legend_Bar_Column : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Chart.DataSource = GetData();
        Cha
```

rt.DataBind();
    }

```
protected DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("yValue"));
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10 });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 30 });
    table.Rows.Add(new object[] { 30 });
    return table;
}
```

}

Feel free to contact me if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Hi Raghu, I am using Line Chart which has <Series>
                    <telerik:ScatterLineSeries. Currently the legends for each lines are shown as single column. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can control the size and columns of the legend somewhat by following the suggestions here, using declarative style such as:

```
    <Legend>
        <Appearance Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220">
        </Appearance>
    </Legend>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/htmlchart/appearance-and-styling/legend-settings